# What is this IC "30=70H"?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification, light, controller

I'm hoping to identify the IC on this Philips Hue lightstrip controller in order to replace it.

The IC blew after a barrel connector head used had its polarity reversed, so 24 V went in the wrong way and melted pin 5 (top row, middle pin on the IC in the picture).

Suggestions on how to identify what it is would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Philips Hue Lightstrip controller PCB]

Comment: It is extremely likely there is far more damage than what you actually see. For you to see damage, something had to fail and then get hot enough for long enough, but ICs are damaged far faster by far less. Repair is a losing proposition since you probably have to replace most, if not every IC on the chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [Richtek RT6208GE](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6208/DS6208-02.pdf). It's a switching power supply (buck regulator) chip (obvious from observing the PCB layout).

I disagree with DKN.. worth trying a replacement in this case for a $1.50 part. I give it better than even odds.

Comment: I think you spot on! Thank your for your reply, that's really helpful!

I will order the part and see if I can repair it and report back.

What resource did you use to figure out what the component was?

Comment: Cerebral cortex + web browser. There really isn't a good way to decode most of the IC part codes.